# Close Angular Material Dialog after create success with NGRX, effects

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to implement Ngrx to my angular project and also using angular material dialog. My goal is pretty simple that i just want to close the dialog after success form submit.

Please let me know what is the best practice to achieve this.

Thanks

department-dialog.component.ts

```
public createDepartment() {
    this.store.dispatch(
        CreateDepartment({ payload: this.departmentForm.value })
    );
}
```

department.effect.ts

```
createDepartment$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(departmentActions.CreateDepartment),
        mergeMap(({ payload }) =>
            this.departmentService.createDepartment(payload).pipe(
                switchMap((response: any) => {
                    return [
                        departmentActions.CreateDepartmentSuccess({
                            department: response.data,
                        }),
                    ];
                }),
                catchError((error) =>
                    of(departmentActions.CreateDepartmentError(error))
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Angular Material Dialog, then you would be able to do this :

```
constructor(private matDialogRef: MatDialogRef) {}

public createDepartment() {
  this.store.dispatch(
      CreateDepartment({ payload: this.departmentForm.value })
  );
  this.dialogRef.close(this.departmentForm.value);
}
```

[Material Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples)

Comment: Hi @Emilien, 
Thanks for your reply, I just want to close the dialog when actions is success,

As i discover, some people license store action on component and some are l execute the code base on state change, So, that why i just would like to make clear the best approach for this solution .

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work if only one material dialog is opened.
When form is saved using ngrx, we can use closeAll method of Material dialog to close all the dialogs.

```
constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

createDepartment$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(departmentActions.CreateDepartment),
        mergeMap(({ payload }) =>
            this.departmentService.createDepartment(payload).pipe(
                map((response: any) => {
                    this.dialog.closeAll(); // Close all Material dialogs
                    return departmentActions.CreateDepartmentSuccess({
                        department: response.data,
                    });
                }),
                catchError(
                    (error) => of(departmentActions.CreateDepartmentError(error))
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch the dialog id along with your payload, in `department-dialog.component.ts`:

```
constructor(
  private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DepartmentDialogComponent>,
) {}

public createDepartment() {
    this.store.dispatch(
        CreateDepartment({
          payload: this.departmentForm.value,
          dialogId: this.dialogRef.id // <-- here
        })
    );
}
```

And then your `department.effects.ts`, also add it the success action:

```
constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

createDepartment$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(departmentActions.CreateDepartment),
        map(({ payload }) =>
            this.departmentService.createDepartment(payload).pipe(
                switchMap((response: any) => departmentActions.CreateDepartmentSuccess({
                    department: response.data,
                    dialogId // <-- here
                }),
                catchError((error) =>
                    of(departmentActions.CreateDepartmentError(error))
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

And then add `dialog.effects.ts`:

```
constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

createDepartment$ = createEffect(
    () => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(departmentActions.CreateDepartmentSuccess),
        tap(({ dialogId }) =>
            const dialog = this.matDialog.getDialogById(dialogId);
            dialog?.close();
        ),
    )
    { dispatch: false },
);
```